# Https require port 80 in url

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, nginx-reverse-proxy

Using Nginx 1.12.1 version
Without port no specified URL will not work for Https i.e https://test.domain.com:80

Below is the code:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        ssl on;
        server_name ~^(?<subdomain>[^.]+)\.domain.com$;

        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/ssl_certificate.cer;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/sslnew.key;

        root /var/www/$subdomain;
        index index.html;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

        }

}
```

If I remove "SSL on" then https will not work but it will work without port no i.e test.domain.com.

Comment: If you **really** want to listen for HTTPS connections on a port 80, which is weird, change `listen 80 default_server;` to `listen 80 ssl default_server;`. But why not to use standard port 443 for this?

Comment: i dont want to listen https on port 80. I tried using port 443 but it is not working at all.

Comment: Your question is really unclear. Please add a clear description what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http` assumes port 80 and `https` assumes port 443. If you want a browser to override these defaults, the port must be specified in the URL.

The correct solution is to provide `http` over port 80 and `https` over port 443, in which case, the port does not need to be provided in the URL and can be assumed from the scheme (`http` or `https`).

For example:

```
server {
    listen  80;
    listen  443 ssl;
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#single_http_https_server) for details.

Comment: I tried this solution but https is not working at all.

Comment: If your server can receive requests on port 80, but not port 443, it’s possibly a firewall problem.

Comment: Thanks. Port was blocked at firewall.